# How to reset a bone transformation issue

Tags: rigging, bones

[image]
I'm not sure what I did but I changed the direction of the eye's bones of my mesh and is messing my mesh. They should all point forward ang now they are pointing up.
Does anybody know how to solve this issue? how to reset my rig to its original setting?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: What happens if you select the bone in Pose mode and hit Alt-R?

Comment: Nothing happens.  They still pointing up. I was in edit mode yesterday doing some adjusments because they were not totally centered on the eye but I ended messing it up, making it worse and dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Try Alt-R in Edit mode and see if that fixes it. If not, I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: No Change. I just uploaded the file here (thank you):  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=rJsD1pxG" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/rJsD1pxG/)

Comment: I've added that link into your question now. Haven't had time to look at the file yet.

Comment: Bones like MCH-lid have damped track constraints targeting bones like lid.T.L.   Lid.T.L isn't transformed, but it has a rest pose that means that it's behind the eye-- it probably shouldn't be.  Don't know exactly what you did to do that-- could be edit mode changes, could be "apply as rest pose" or something.

Comment: I think someone with more experience with rigging than me is going to have to look at your file. The actual eye bones seem to be oriented correctly, but it's the ones which open and close the eyes which are wrong by the look of it.  The one thing I have noticed is that you didn't apply the scale to your armature and your model before you started parenting and generating the rig. That's why the rig is so large relative to your model. You'll need to delete the rig, unparent your model and start again. - I see an expert ( @Nathan) has now arrived so I'll bow out!

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I just don't recall deleting the metarig, can't find it and so can't generate new rig again out of it.  Could you please tell me how to apply scale?

Comment: In Object mode, you would select your model and then Ctrl-A > Scale. If you have the N-panel open you would see that the scale changes from .137 to 1 in all directions. **However** I'm no expert on rigging so I'd be reluctant to do that with the model already rigged without advice from others.. In fact, you'll see that rig.003 shows a scale of .387 but resetting the scale of that with the same method completely screws up the model in Object mode. (Ctrl-Z to undo if you were to try it...)